# Making a search of course/teacher with Ajax and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery Ajax problem.

I have a select tag with options of courses, the select holds div id="course". I have a button with id of "go" and an empty div with id of "courseInfo". I need to make it so that when a course number is selected, the teacher name in my php file that goes with it is displayed on the page. I have all my Ajax written, everything is linked, but it wont work and no error when I debug.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
findCourse = function(){

var file = "Course.php?course="+$("#course").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: file,
    datatype : "text",
    success : function(response) {

    $("#courseInfo").html(response); 
    }

});

}

clear = function(){
    $("#courseInfo").html("");
};

$("#course").click(clear);
$("#go").click(findCourse);
});
```

**Form:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="course" id="course">
<option value="420-121">420-121</option>
<option value="420-122">420-122</option>
<option value="420-123">420-123</option>
<option value="420-221">420-221</option>
<option value="420-222">420-222</option>
<option value="420-223">420-223</option>
<option value="420-224">420-224</option>

</select>
Select a course to see the course name and teacher assigned<br><br>
<input type="button" id="go" value="go!">

</form>
<br><br>
<div id="courseInfo"></div>
```

Comment: missing `=` after `course` -> `var file = "Course.php?course="+$("#course").val();`

Comment: I added it, thank you. It still doesnt work, however :/

Comment: have you checked your browser console to see if the `$.ajax()` has fired?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML of the div and button as well please?

Comment: Are you checking on the receiving end that it actually is send to the file in the file course.php you place: error_log("course.php ".print_r($_GET))?

You could also try:
.....
var file = "Course.php;
var TheData=$("#course).val();
.....
url: "course.php",
data: (course:TheData),
...

Comment: I have included my html code above.

Comment: It says that my ajax can't load

Comment: We were provided the php file, we havent learnt it yet in my course :)

Comment: is `ajax can't load` the actual error message? or does it give an actual error message?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Course%20Info/Course.php?course=420-121. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: you are not accessing this page on a webserver, ie. `localhost`, as it is trying to access `Course.php` locally -> `file:///C:/...`

Comment: In that case Im not sure how my previous Ajax assignment worked while this one doesnt :/ Could you please explain to me how I could go about this, I'd be very grateful. I started learning Ajax less than a week ago.

Comment: in your browser how are you accessing this page? ie. `http://`, `localhost://`, `file://C:`?

Comment: Its being accessed like this when I run from my server:

Comment: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Course%20Info/Course.html

Comment: you are accessing it as a local file, not as a web file through your server.

Comment: I have it in my htdocs folder in my xampp server. I'm running it from there as my teacher instructed me. I wasn't told what else I had to do so I am a little lost as to what I should do next.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the PHP side is working properly, the code below should fix the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    findCourse = function(){
        var file = "Course.php?course="+$("#course").val();
        console.log(file);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: file,
            datatype : "text",
            success : function(response) {
                $("#courseInfo").html(response); 
            }
        });

    }

    clear = function(){
        $("#courseInfo").html("");
    };

    $("#course").click(clear);
    $("#go").click(findCourse);
});
```

You miss the `=` in `var file`.

Yours was

`var file = "Course.php?course"+$("#course").val();`

It should be

`var file = "Course.php?course="+$("#course").val();`

Comment: Yes this was pointed out to me and I had changed it but it has not resolved my issue. The php file was made by my teacher

Comment: Please tell me that you're running that page in a web server environment, not a local machine. @CodePrincess94

Comment: Yes I am, xampp. I have another code assignment I finished earlier today using ajax that I was running in it and it worked perfectly.